# Personal SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, testing, certificate, ca

I have a couple of servers running inside a test environment I have a single CA and could certify one page.

Is it possible to create my own CA for the test environments derived from the CA I received?

Answer (score 0):

You can use java development tool **`keytool`** to create your own certificate for a server on same machine on which your server will be running. You have to configure your server with that certificate.

It will ask you some information, enter and continue, and you will be your own CA.

Following is the command to generate certificate for Apache Tomcat:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Comment: Hi S Jayesh,
Thanks for the answer but that will certify 1 server only I have a couple of them in the environment.

Comment: It depends on: 1st whether you are using different servers for same service with load balancer, or 2nd using different servers to serve different services, or 3rd using same machine having different servers on it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a single CA and could certify one page.

Given the wording of "could certify one page" I guess that you don't have a single CA (certification authority) as you claim but that you instead have a single server certificate which is issued by a CA. Such server certificates can not be used to issue new certificates, only CA certificates can do this.

> Is it possible to create my own CA for the test environments derived from the CA I received?

While you can create your own CA you cannot derive it from the server certificate you've got and thus essentially from the CA which signed the server certificate. This means the certificates you've created with your own CA will only be automatically trusted by your clients if they've explicitly added your own CA to their trust stores.